# AEM unpublished page is still visible on publish instance

Tags: components, adobe, aem, publish, author

last time I do some updated.

I uploaded to CRX installed and did replication.

On component A works ok (author & & publisher)
On component B on author works have new data, publisher have old data

What I saw is when I unpublished page with component B is still visible on publisher instance.

Comment: can you open the same page with query paramenters ? Maybe it's just cached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replicate a package that contains a deactivated page, that page will be still visible because AEM ignores the deactivated status on the publish instance, if the page exists it will be displayed. To avoid this:

1. Do not replicate deactivated pages via package.
2. And/or use the on/off property where a page won't be available even if it exists in the publish instance. See https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-64/classic-ui/authoring/classic-page-author-publish-pages.html?lang=en#scheduled-activation-deactivation-on-off-time